# Consuming WCF service using NetTcpBinding in a UWP app

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, uwp

I am currently in the process of migrating all of our applications over to the Windows 10 UWP platform. We were coming from the Windows 8.1 platform and we were using a WCF service to send both data as well as files to and from a server running our service.

This worked great in Windows 8.1 since it fully supported the uploading of files to a WCF service that had a `nettcpbinding`. However, according to numerous posts on here as well as the MSDN forums, nettcpbinding is not currently supported on UWP. Whenever I try to run our app and upload a file to our server I get `PlatformNotSupportedException` when it tries to upload.

The issue here is that while I could roll my own socket classes to upload this file, I find it hard to believe that Microsoft would've released UWP without basic support for nettcpbindings. On top of this it appears that the .NET library that is included in UWP apps does not have support for native FTP so I cannot do that either.

Has anyone had any experience in getting nettcpbindings to work with UWP? If I try to circumvent my proxy classes that I have made manually with "Add Service Reference" it ends up generating the upload method with an incorrect signature. The signature is supposed to be `UploadFileAsync(RemoteFileInfo info)` but is turned into `UploadFileInfo(byte[] info` when using "Add Service Reference".

Any ideas?

Comment: NetTcpBinding works if you use `SecurityMode.None`, otherwise I've not managed to get it working so far.

Comment: I've come across the same issue as the OP. I believe this has to do with the fact that the default security mode for NetTcp is "Transport" and if you have a look at this post here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38312b93-6e01-4a1d-bbe2-15a4f5b5d6e1/uwpsystemplatformnotsupportedexception-occurred-in-systemprivateservicemodeldll?forum=wpdevelop it seems as though this is not supported yet? As Bjorn suggested changing the security mode to none should work in theory but I haven't had any luck with that approach... I no longer receive an exception but my call just hangs.

Comment: It would be good if someone was able to post an update on this situation!